# Generating unique IDs for new records and existing records

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-crm-365

I'm basically trying to create a primary ID between CRM and QuickBooks. Figured I'd just use the existing PK in CRM for the lookup. I'd like the PK to visible to the user, but not editable in CRM.

This has presented several problems in that you can't do that out of the box. I thought I read somewhere you could either via business rule or calculated field, but I haven't had luck with that.

It sounds like it would require web resources if I were to go this route.

The other option would be to just generate unique values for every record in Accounts and Contacts.

Does this automatically populate existing records or just new records? How do I get it to populate existing records?

Comment: Dynamics 365 now has a built-in autonumber field type (you need to use XrmToolbox - or similar, to configure it)

Comment: Which option you end up with?

Comment: Hi, I am working with your suggestion. Having trouble getting the numbering on existing records so haven't accepted as of yet. Working on it right now actually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Auto number manager](https://jonasrapp.net/2017/10/anm/) for configuring an auto-number attribute in every entity. This seeds a number based on configured format for new records. Uniqueness assured by SQL sequence feature & no need of any extra plugin/workflow.

For existing records - you can design a workflow along with a temp entity to assign auto-number. [Read more](https://jonasrapp.net/2019/02/anm-existing/).

Otherwise you can use SSIS + Kingswaysoft package to generate auto-number & assign for existing records.

Answer (score 0):

I am suggesting you to create a new text field on the entity and create a pre plugin that will get the record primary GUID id from context and will set this GUID into the newly added attribute. You can set this field as read-only of form as well.

OR you can generate new GUID as well into the plugin.